# Returning 'true' after validation function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, validation

I trying to verify that some fields have valid input before continuing. I want to only validate a few fields prior to form submission. The validation is working correctly and displaying errors where necessary. But when all fields are valid, it seems to not return to the calling function to continue?

```
function validateTableRow() {
    $('input[name="addPid"]').valid();
    $('input[name="addName"]').valid();
    $('input[name="addAddress"]').valid();
    $('input[name="addCity"]').valid();
    $('select[name="addState"]').valid();
    $('input[name="addZip"]').valid();
}

$('.button').click(function () {
    if(validateTableRow()){
        //Do something
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Because you don't `return` anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `validateTableRow()` has to return `true` in order to do the `//Do something`. But is not returning anything, to JS that's `false`, so whatever you put inside the `if` will not be done.

You can change the function to return `true` or `false` depending on what you want:

```
function validateTableRow() {
  return  $('input[name="addPid"]').valid() &&
    $('input[name="addName"]').valid() &&
    $('input[name="addAddress"]').valid() &&
    $('input[name="addCity"]').valid() &&
    $('select[name="addState"]').valid() &&
    $('input[name="addZip"]').valid();
}

$('.button').click(function () {
    if(validateTableRow()){
    //Do something
    }
});
}
```

[EDIT]
To check them all before returning `true` or `false`, could be like this:

```
function validateTableRow() {

    $('input[name="addPid"]').valid();
    $('input[name="addName"]').valid();
    $('input[name="addAddress"]').valid();
    $('input[name="addCity"]').valid();
    $('select[name="addState"]').valid();
    $('input[name="addZip"]').valid();

    return  $('input[name="addPid"]').valid() &&
        $('input[name="addName"]').valid() &&
        $('input[name="addAddress"]').valid() &&
        $('input[name="addCity"]').valid() &&
        $('select[name="addState"]').valid() &&
        $('input[name="addZip"]').valid();
    }

    $('.button').click(function () {
        if(validateTableRow()){
        //Do something
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: This kinda works. When I click on a blank form, only the first field shows the error message. If I fill in that field, then click, then the second blank field displays the error. All then way until all fields are valid, then it returns true and continues. But the behavior of only returning one validation error seems strange?

Comment: Yes, correct, the operator && returns false when something is false, but doesnt "read" what's next. I'll explain, if you have statement1 && statement2, and statement1 is false, it doesnt execute staement2. because the whole statement is going to be false anyway. Saves time. So if the first one returns invalid, it's not going to check if the next ones are valid or not.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Would there be a way to check all 6 inputs before returning true or false?

Comment: You can put all the checks before the return statement, it's a little dirty but should work. I'll edit answer.

Comment: Thanks @Pablo Viñals, works perfectly. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything from your method.

Make it (assuming that `valid` method returns a boolean)

```
function validateTableRow() {
    return $('input[name="addPid"]').valid()  && $('input[name="addName"]').valid() &&   $('input[name="addAddress"]').valid() &&  $('input[name="addCity"]').valid() &&  $('select[name="addState"]').valid() &&   $('input[name="addZip"]').valid();
}

$('.button').click(function () {
    if(validateTableRow()){
        //Do something
    }
});
}
```